# Having issues binding tkinter text boxes and check boxes to my SQLite database using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am new to programming in general and am trying my hand at working on a simple prototype of a simple database insert/retrieval gui on a 4x4 grid of checkbutton/textbox units.

I have successfully made a table in SQLite3 with 32 (16 text/16 checkutton) appropriate columns.

Right now I am trying to bind these fields to their respective columns and would like to make new rows using a save button

...but I keep getting this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "checkbutton": syntax error
```

I'm am trying to run this code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mainRecs.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO recsTable (rec1, rec1 checkbutton,\
    rec2, rec2 checkbutton,\
    rec3, rec3 checkbutton,\
    rec4, rec4 checkbutton,\
    rec5, rec5 checkbutton,\
    rec6, rec6 checkbutton,\
    rec7, rec7 checkbutton,\
    rec8, rec8 checkbutton,\
    rec9, rec9 checkbutton,\
    rec10, rec10 checkbutton,\
    rec11, rec11 checkbutton,\
    rec12, rec12 checkbutton,\
    rec13, rec13 checkbutton,\
    rec14, rec14 checkbutton,\
    rec15, rec15 checkbutton,\
    rec16, rec16 checkbutton) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,\
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,\
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (strVar1, checkVar1, strVar2, checkVar2,
    strVar3, checkVar3, strVar4, checkVar4,
    strVar5, checkVar5, strVar6, checkVar6,
    strVar7, checkVar7, strVar8, checkVar8,
    strVar9, checkVar9, strVar10, checkVar10,
    strVar11, checkVar11, strVar12, checkVar12,
    strVar13, checkVar13, strVar14, checkVar14,
    strVar15, checkVar15, strVar16, checkVar16))
conn.commit()
```

Lower in my script, I have the following code for each of the 16 "recs"

```
checkVar1 = IntVar()
chk1 = Checkbutton(root, variable=checkVar1)
chk1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NE)
Label(root, text="Rec 1").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
strVar1 = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=strVar1)
e1.grid(row=4, column=0)
strVar1.set("Enter Rec Label")
```

Any pointers as to what I am missing would be greatly appreciated!

I've looked around, pretty much all day and still can't wrap my head around what I'm missing, or if I'm even phrasing the problem correctly

if you have time to review these bits of code, some feedback would be tremendously helpful.

Thank you!

-T

Comment: You must use quotes on field names with `spaces`, like `"rec1 checkbutton"`.

Comment: or use in database column names without spaces ie. `rec1_checkbutton`

Comment: as for feedback: you could use list with variables `strVar[1], strVar[2], etc` and `checkVar[1], checkVar[2], etc.` then you can use `for` loop to do some things - ie. you can create checkboxes in `for` loop. And you can easily add more checkboxes without adding new code.

Comment: prefered names for functions and variables: `lower_case` ie. `str_var`, `str_var`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value from an `IntVar` you must use the `get` method (eg: `checkVar1.get()`) This is mentioned everywhere `IntVar` is documented.

You also have the problem of the phrase `rec1 checkbutton` in the SQL. That is illegal SQL. You need to put quotes around column names that contain spaces (and notice the use of triple quotes around the entire expression):

```
def data_entry():
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO recsTable (rec1, "rec1 checkbutton",
    rec2, "rec2 checkbutton",
    ...
    ''')
```

Though, are you certain you have column names with spaces in them? That seems highly unusual, and makes working with your tables more difficult (as evidenced by this question...)

Comment: Thank you!  I've tried  checkVar1.get() and .get() on all of the other variables, but it presents the same syntax error.

Comment: @TJBlack31: I've updated my answer to address that problem, too.